# Subdivision of a triangle in HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl

How can I subdivide a triangle more than once. I can not use recursion as directx 11 hlsl will not allow it. Are there any links to a HLSL code. This has to be done in the geometry shader as my book says.

my code that will subdivide once is:

```
  void Subdivide(VertexOut inVerts[3], out VertexOut outVerts[6])
{
    //          1
    //          *
    //         / \
    //        /   \
    //     m0*-----*m1
    //      / \   / \
    //     /   \ /   \
    //    *-----*-----*
    //   0     m2     2

    VertexOut m[3];

inVerts[0].PosL = normalize(inVerts[0].PosL);
inVerts[1].PosL = normalize(inVerts[1].PosL);
inVerts[2].PosL = normalize(inVerts[2].PosL);
// compute edge midpoints
m[0].PosL = 0.5f * (inVerts[0].PosL + inVerts[1].PosL);
m[1].PosL = 0.5f * (inVerts[1].PosL + inVerts[2].PosL);
m[2].PosL = 0.5f * (inVerts[2].PosL + inVerts[0].PosL);
m[0].PosL = normalize(m[0].PosL);
m[1].PosL = normalize(m[1].PosL);
m[2].PosL = normalize(m[2].PosL);

    // derive normals
    m[0].NormalL = m[0].PosL;
    m[1].NormalL = m[1].PosL;
    m[2].NormalL = m[2].PosL;

    // interpolate texture coordinates
    m[0].Tex = 0.5f * (inVerts[0].Tex + inVerts[1].Tex);
    m[1].Tex = 0.5f * (inVerts[1].Tex + inVerts[2].Tex);
    m[2].Tex = 0.5f * (inVerts[2].Tex + inVerts[0].Tex);

    outVerts[0] = inVerts[0];
    outVerts[1] = m[0];
    outVerts[2] = m[2];
    outVerts[3] = m[1];
    outVerts[4] = inVerts[2];
    outVerts[5] = inVerts[1];
}

void OutputSubdivision(VertexOut v[6], inout TriangleStream<GeoOut> stream)
{
    GeoOut gout[6];

    [unroll]
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        // Transform to World Space
        gout[i].PosW = mul(float4(v[i].PosL, 1.0f), gWorld).xyz;
        gout[i].NormalW = mul(v[i].NormalL, (float3x3)gWorldInvTranspose);

        // Transform to homogeneous clip space
        gout[i].PosH = mul(float4(v[i].PosL, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);

        gout[i].Tex = v[i].Tex;
    }

    //          1
    //          *
    //         / \
    //        /   \
    //     m0*-----*m1
    //      / \   / \
    //     /   \ /   \
    //    *-----*-----*
    //   0     m2     2

    // We can draw the subdivision in two strips:
    // strip 1: bottom three triangles
    // strip 2: top triangle

    [unroll]
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
    {
        stream.Append(gout[j]);
    }
    stream.RestartStrip();

    stream.Append(gout[1]);
    stream.Append(gout[5]);
    stream.Append(gout[3]);



    }


[maxvertexcount(8)]
void GS(triangle VertexOut gin[3], inout TriangleStream<GeoOut> stream)
{   
    VertexOut v[6];


    Subdivide(gin, v);

    OutputSubdivision(v, stream);
}
```

How can I subdivide twice or even three or four times.
thx

Comment: Out of interest, why would one subdivide a triangle in a shader? The normals etc. of the sub triangles remain the same as the source so I am wondering what the application of this technique would be.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use the geometry shader to sub-divide primitives, I would suggest looking into [tessellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476340(v=vs.85).aspx). It is a new feature that has been added in DirectX 11, which allows you to sub-divide low level primitives into high-detailed primitives. This feature is highly optimized to do the exact thing you are describing. See the image below for an example.

[image]

Without going into too much detail, the tessellation pipeline consists of three new stages: [hull shader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476339(v=vs.85).aspx), [fixed-function tessellator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476341(v=vs.85).aspx) and [domain shader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476337(v=vs.85).aspx). Simply put, the hull shader defines the positions of new points inside original primitive, which are passed to the fixed-function tessellator stage. The domain shader runs on the output of the tessellator. You can think of the domain shader as a replacement of the vertex shader of sorts, as stuff that you would normally put in the vertex shader are now placed in the domain shader.

To get any more information I would suggest to look for documentation and tutorials (like [this one](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut38.html), for example)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this post](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/635147-subdividing-triangles-with-the-geometry-shader/) on gamedev.net.

Try to use their code, and correct the Vertex Positions.

Try creating a method that implements a barycentric function, and use the generated coords to create 3 triangle. For example,
you should generate this:

[image: Barycentric diagram as .svg file]

Use the coordinates of the line segments that form 3 equal triangles

I have a bit of code to generate a barrycentric function, but it is written in Java, so you may have to translate/port it:

```
public static float barryCentric(Vector3f p1,Vector3f p2, Vector3f p3, Vector2f pos){
    float det = (p2.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p1.z - p3.z);
    float eleven = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) /det;
    float tweleve = ((p3.z - p1.z) * (pos.x - p3.x) + (p1.x - p3.x) * (pos.y - p3.z)) /det;
    float thirteen = 1.0f - eleven - tweleve;
    return eleven * p1.y + tweleve * p2.y + thirteen * p3.y;
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it summarized the main techniques demonstrated by the link, so that it can stand on its own if that forum thread ever becomes unavailable.